# Problem assigning values to a matrix from cell arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

I am trying to do the following (in MATLAB), but it fails:

```
% obj is a 2x1 cell array.
% obj{:,:}.one.two is a 1x32 vector.
% obj{:,:}.one.two.profiles.profile is a 1x5 vector.


a = obj{1,1}.one;
b = obj{2,1}.one;

delta = zeros(32,5);

for i = 1:32
    for j = 1:5
        delta(i,j) = a.two(1,i).profiles.profile(1,j) - b.two(1,i).profiles.profile(1,j);
    end
end
```

The generated error:

"Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 2 results."

Could you please help? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: please create a MCVE (where a and b are defined)

Comment: Could you please also supply the obj cell array?